# Can NetCDF be returned with WCS 1.0.0 using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, wcs

I am able to get NetCDF files to return using this request:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?request=GetCoverage&service=WCS&version=2.0.1&coverageId=it.geosolutions__rhum&Format=application/x-netcdf&subset=http://www.opengis.net/def/axis/OGC/0/Long(5,20)&subset=http://www.opengis.net/def/axis/OGC/0/Lat(40,50)`

However, I'd like to use WCS 1.0.0 instead. When I modify the request to the following:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?request=GetCoverage&service=WCS&version=1.0.0&coverage=it.geosolutions:rhum&Format=NetCDF&bbox=5,40,20,50&width=500&height=500&elevation=2&CRS=EPSG:4326`

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NetCDF encoding only supports granuleStack coverages
NetCDF encoding only supports granuleStack coverages
```

I'm not sure what this means and if it's just a limitation of WCS 1.0.0.

Can I get NetCDF files to return using WCS 1.0.0 with the NetCDF plugins?

Comment: I think it is better to stick with WCS 2.0. Same kind of trouble in this thread with WCS 1.0.0 https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/AC013F62DB7E734488432E49211493AC2B7EE5F4%40FRCRPVV9EX3MSX.ww931.my-it-solutions.net/#msg35456291.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only WCS 2.0 can build the granule stack structure needed to encode an ND raster dataset.